Fourier transform and periodization of a discrete time signal
I'm stuck with this Fourier transform assignment and would appreciate any help I can get...
I have a signal $s(t)=3^{-|t|}$ where $s: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{C}$. I use $\sum_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}s(t)e^{-i2\pi t\nu}$ to calculate the Fourier transform and $N\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}\hat{s}(\nu -kN)$ to periodize that transform. By combining these I get:
$$\hat{s} _{N}(\nu)=N\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}^{} \sum_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}3^{-|t|}e^{-i2\pi t(\nu-kN)}$$
which expands to:
$$\hat{s} _{N}(\nu)=N\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}^{} \sum_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}3^{-|t|}e^{-i2\pi t\nu}e^{i2\pi tkN}$$
With $t$, $k$ and $N$ being integers $e^{i2\pi tkN}=1$ which in turn simplifies the equation to:
$$\hat{s} _{N}(\nu)=N \sum_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}3^{-|t|}e^{-i2\pi t\nu}
$$
So now $\hat{s} _{47}(2)$, which I want to calculate is:
$$\hat{s} _{47}(2)=47 \sum_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}3^{-|t|}e^{-i4\pi t}$$
Because $e^{-i4\pi t}=1$ for all $t\in\mathbb{Z}$ the expression simplifies even further to:
$$\hat{s} _{47}(2)=47 \sum_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}^{}3^{-|t|}=47\left( \frac{3^{-1}}{1-3^{-1}}+1+\frac{3^{-1}}{1-3^{-1}} \right)=47\left( \frac{3}{6}+1+\frac{3}{6} \right)=94$$
However 94 doesn't seem to be the right answer. What am I doing wrong here?

$\hat{s}{N}(\nu) = \sum\limits{t \in Z} 3^{-|t|} e^{\frac{-i 2 \pi t \nu}{N}}$ if I understand your notation right. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform

If I understand correctly that would be the periodic and discrete $s:\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{C}$ Fourier transform (or DFT). My signal is discrete but not periodic, ie $s:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{C}$. The concepts are a bit confusing, though. And I suspect that I've gotten something wrong with understanding the assignment..!

If time domain is discrete and non periodic, frequency domain is periodic and continuous

Really? I understand that the frequency domain is continuous, but is it necessarily periodic? I mean periodicity isn't implied in $\hat{s}(\nu)=\sum_{t\in \mathrm{Z}}^{}s(t)e^{-i2\pi t\nu}$

Yes, it's periodic. The Wikipedia link I sent has the details. See $S_{\frac{1}{T}}(f)$ formula. I interpreted your $N= \frac{1}{T}$. With appropriate normalization, DTFT is $2\pi$ periodic.

Ok, now I think I got it. The $2\pi$ periodicity is in the simplifications I made, right? Where $e^{i2\pi}$ (and whatever integer multiples in the exponent) is simplified to 1? How would you solve the problem of getting $\hat{s}_{N}(\nu)$ when given $s(t)=3^{-|t|}$?
